# Swapping rows in 2-D array C++

Tags: c++, arrays, multidimensional-array, bubble-sort

So yeah, I wrote a program which sort rows of two-dimensional array in ascending order according to sum of all positive even elements in every row, BUT it does not work properly. Sometimes it can swap rows correctly but mostly it feels like this program only swap two adjacent rows or something like that.

Probably, there is a problem with incorrect using bubble sort for 2-d arrays. Here is the function where I did most things:

```
void print(int** arr, int rows, int columns) {
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < columns; j++) {
            cout << setw(7) << arr[i][j];
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
    int* sumRows = new int[rows];
    int sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < columns; j++) {
            if (arr[i][j] > 0 && arr[i][j] % 2 == 0)
            {
                //cout << setw(7) << arr[i][j];
                sum = sum + arr[i][j];
            }
        }
        cout << endl << "Sum of positive even elements in the row " << i + 1 << " = " << sum;
        sumRows[i] = sum;
        sum = 0;
    }
    cout << endl << "Array of sums: ";
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
        cout << setw(7) << sumRows[i];
    }

    //for (int i = 0; i < r; i++) cout << setw(7) << sumRows[i];
    cout << endl;

    bool swapped;
    for (int i = 0; i < rows - 1; i++)
    {
        swapped = false;
        for (int j = 0; j < columns - 1; j++)
        {
            for (int k = 0; k < rows - i - 1; k++) {
                if (sumRows[k] > sumRows[k + 1])
                {
                    swap(arr[k][j], arr[k + 1][j]);
                    swapped = true;
                }
            }
        }

        if (swapped == false) break;
    }

    cout << endl << endl << "Swapped array:" << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < columns; j++) {
            cout << setw(7) << arr[i][j];
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
}
```

Full code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <time.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

int** createMalloc(int, int);
int** createCalloc(int rows, int columns);

int** createNew(int rows, int columns);
void deleteNew(int** arr, int rows);

void init(int**, int, int);
void freeMemory(int**, int);
void print(int**, const int, const int);

void initPrint(int** arr, int rows, int columns);

void main() {
    int rowCount, colCount;
    cout << "Enter number of rows: "; cin >> rowCount;
    cout << "Enter number of columns: "; cin >> colCount;
    cout << " Array creation algorithm\n";
start:
    cout << "Input number : \n1 for malloc\n2 for calloc\n3 for new\n";
    int k;
    cin >> k;
    switch (k) {
    case 1: {
        int** a = createMalloc(rowCount, colCount);
        initPrint(a, rowCount, colCount);

        freeMemory(a, rowCount);
        break;
    }
    case 2: {
        int** a = createCalloc(rowCount, colCount);
        initPrint(a, rowCount, colCount);

        freeMemory(a, rowCount);
        break;
    }
    case 3: {
        int** a = createNew(rowCount, colCount);
        initPrint(a, rowCount, colCount);

        deleteNew(a, rowCount);
        break;
    }
    default:cout << "Input 1, 2 or 3, please.";
        cout << endl << endl;
        goto start;
    }
    cout << endl << endl;
}

int** createMalloc(int rows, int columns) {
    int** arr = (int**)malloc(rows * sizeof(int*));
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
        arr[i] = (int*)malloc(columns * sizeof(int));
    }
    return arr;
}

int** createCalloc(int rows, int columns) {
    int** arr = (int**)calloc(rows, sizeof(int*));
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
        arr[i] = (int*)calloc(columns, sizeof(int));
    }
    return arr;
}

int** createNew(int rows, int columns) {
    int** arr = new int* [rows];
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
        arr[i] = new int[columns];
    }
    return arr;
}

void initPrint(int** arr, int rows, int columns) {
    init(arr, rows, columns);
    print(arr, rows, columns);
}

void init(int** arr, int rows, int columns) {
    const int Low = -10, High = 10;
    srand((unsigned)time(NULL));
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < columns; j++) {
            arr[i][j] = Low + rand() % (High - Low + 1);
        }
    }
}

void freeMemory(int** arr, int rows) {
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
        free(arr[i]);
    }
    free(arr);
}

void deleteNew(int** arr, int rows) {
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
        delete[] arr[i];
    }
    delete[] arr;
}

void print(int** arr, int rows, int columns) {
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < columns; j++) {
            cout << setw(7) << arr[i][j];
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
    int* sumRows = new int[rows];
    int sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < columns; j++) {
            if (arr[i][j] > 0 && arr[i][j] % 2 == 0)
            {
                //cout << setw(7) << arr[i][j];
                sum = sum + arr[i][j];
            }
        }
        cout << endl << "Sum of positive even elements in the row " << i + 1 << " = " << sum;
        sumRows[i] = sum;
        sum = 0;
    }
    cout << endl << "Array of sums: ";
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
        cout << setw(7) << sumRows[i];
    }

    //for (int i = 0; i < r; i++) cout << setw(7) << sumRows[i];
    cout << endl;

    bool swapped;
    for (int i = 0; i < rows - 1; i++)
    {
        swapped = false;
        for (int j = 0; j < columns - 1; j++)
        {
            for (int k = 0; k < rows - i - 1; k++) {
                if (sumRows[k] > sumRows[k + 1])
                {
                    swap(arr[k][j], arr[k + 1][j]);
                    swapped = true;
                }
            }
        }

        //IF no two elements were swapped by inner loop, then break 
        if (swapped == false) break;
    }

    cout << endl << endl << "Swapped array:" << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < columns; j++) {
            cout << setw(7) << arr[i][j];
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
}
```

P.S. Two-dimensional arrays must be necessarily dynamic ones. Besides, I needed to give user a choice of creating an array with `malloc`, `calloc` or `new`. Also, cannot do this task using `vector` yet.

P.P.S. I know that most of you will find it easy but for me it is definitely not as this task is my homework in a university and we have not learnt any sorting algorithms. Anyway, when I asked the teacher how can I sort rows like that, he told me to use bubble sort so here I am

Comment: You have my deep sympathy for being taught c++ without being allowed to use… even if the point is to teach you resource management, a real C++ program would use algorithms. Anyway: split your logic into functions, it will make it much easier to reason about and find issues :)

Comment: Ad the very least: summing elements is a task in itself, so it should be its own function. Same for sorting.

Comment: if the point of the exercise isn't to avoid `std::vector` then use it. If it is, then write your own. Manual memory managment isnt something you should scatter around in your code, it should be encapsulated in a class that deals with it (and nothing else)

Comment: When you swap two rows, you also need to swap corresponding values in `sumRows`. Otherwise, the sums no longer correspond to actual values in the rows.

Comment: You don't need to go column by column to swap two rows. Just simply `std::swap(arr[k], arr[k+1])`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What actually helped me:

```
void swapInitial(int** arr, int* sumRows, int rows, int columns) {
    bool swapped;
    for (int i = 0; i < rows - 1; i++)
    {
        swapped = false;

        for (int k = 0; k < rows - i - 1; k++) {
            if (sumRows[k] > sumRows[k + 1])
            {
                swap(arr[k], arr[k + 1]); 
                swap(sumRows[k], sumRows[k + 1]); 
                swapped = true;
            }
        }

        if (swapped == false) break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The 3 loops worries me so I went to [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_sort) to check my assumptions.

Totally untested code, use at own risk

```cpp
void BSort(int **arr, int *sumRows, int rows, int columns) {
    bool swapped;
    while (true) {
        swapped = false;
        for (int k = 0; k < rows - 1; k++, rows--) { // reduce max row
            if (sumRows[k] > sumRows[k + 1]) {
                swap(arr[k], arr[k + 1]); // swaps the pointers
                swap(sumRows[k], sumRows[k + 1]); // swap the sums too or we swap on false conditions afterward.
                swapped = true;
            }
        }

        if (swapped == false) break;
    }
}
```

further

- you should exchange your goto loop with a while somehow.
- sumRows is not getting deleted.
- use smaller blocks of code, use functions for sumRows, Bubble Sort etc.

Comment: fwiw, `swapped` can be initialized in the first line and `swapped = false` be removed. The loop is never entered with `swapped == false` due to the `break`

Comment: @largest_prime_is_463035818 if I understand the wiki correctly, the swapped needs to be reset every loop so we can see if we are finished.

Comment: Updated due to Igors comments about swapping the sumRows.

Answer (score 1):

Basically your program is already good. (Except the sorting problem)

But, I would like to show to you a more "C++-style" solution using an object oriented approach.

And this is a comlplete and tested code, with tons of comments, to allow for an easy understanding.

We encapsulate all our data in a class and add methods to operate on that data. We do this, because the outside world should not be interested in our internal data representation. We can change the class internals and nobody in the rest of the world should notice it.

Additionally, all functions of the class can access the data of the class. So, we do not pollute the namespace with unneccessary data.

The implementation of the allocation method is just an exercise and adds not so much value. It is just typing work.

To make output simple, we overwrite the class' inserter operator. That is not complicated at all and allows us an intuitive usage of the existing ostreams, like `std::cout`.

In the sort function you had a problem. You just want to sort the rows by a given predicate: The sum of the even positive numbers in the column of the row.

Please note: There is no need to touch any column data. If a swap is necessary, we just swap the pointer to the needed rows. So, not many column values, just one pointer of the row that points to the first column value. This is very efficient.

Please note. In this example, you cannot precalculate the sum of a the rows, because the rows need to be swapped.

If we wanted to do that, we need to introduce a data structure, consisting of column values and the sums. Also easily possible. Or, in case of an additional precalculated array for row sums, we would need to swap also those values as well. But in the below solution we go the easy way and recalculate the row value everytime, and waste a lot of time with that . . .

Anyway. Please check the below example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
#include <algorithm>

// Lower and Upper Bound of our random test values
constexpr int LowerBound = -10;
constexpr int UpperBound = 10;

// We may have 3 different types of allocators
enum class Allocater { New, Malloc, Calloc};

// An ultra simple, stripped down representation of a 2d array with 3 types of allocaters
class Array2D {
    const Allocater allocater{};                    // Type of allocator. Default is new
    const size_t numberOfRows{};                    // Number of Rows in the 2d array
    const size_t numberOfColumns{};                 // Number of Columns of our 2d array
    int** data{};

    void allocaterMalloc();                         // Allocation using malloc
    void allocaterCalloc();                         // Allocation using calloc
    void allocaterNew();                            // Allocation using new
    void deallocateMallocCalloc();                  // Deallocatio using calloc and malloc
    void deallocateNew();                           // Deallocation using new 
    void initData();                                // Initialize our 2d array with random data
    int sumOfPositiveEvenValuesIn(size_t row) const;// Predicate function to calculate row sums for even positive values 

public:
    // Constructor. Buidl an array with given number of rows and columns using a given allocator implementation
    explicit Array2D(const size_t numRows, const size_t numColumns, Allocater alloc = Allocater::New);
    Array2D() = delete;                             // No default constructor
    ~Array2D();                                     // Free all allocated memory

    friend std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream& os, const Array2D& a2d); // Simple output
    void sort();                                    // Sort according to predicate
};

// ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Main constructor. Build a 2d array with given number of rows and columns using the given allocator method
Array2D::Array2D(const size_t numRows, const size_t numColumns, Allocater alloc) : allocater(alloc), numberOfRows(numRows), numberOfColumns(numColumns) {
    // Depending on the requested method, allocate the memory for our 2d array
    switch (allocater) {
    case Allocater::Malloc:                         // We shall us malloc
        allocaterMalloc();                          // Call apropriate allocater
        break;
    case Allocater::Calloc:                         // We shall use calloc
        allocaterCalloc();                          // Call apropriate allocater
        break;
    case Allocater::New: // Fallthrough             // We shal use new
    default:                                        // Or, if there is some unknown specifier (should never happen)
        allocaterNew();                             // Call apropriate allocater
        break;
    }
    if (data) initData();                           // And initialize our 2d array with random values
}

// Destructor: Release all allocated memory 
Array2D::~Array2D() {
    // Call appropriate deallocator
    if (allocater == Allocater::Malloc || allocater == Allocater::Calloc)
        deallocateMallocCalloc();                   // Deallocate using std::free
    else
        deallocateNew();                            // Deallocate using delete
}

// --------------------------------
// The different alloctor functions

void Array2D::allocaterMalloc() {

    // First get memory to store the row pointer that will later point to the first coulmn of the row
    data = static_cast<int**>(std::malloc(numberOfRows * sizeof(int*)));

    // Now get space for all coulmns in this row
    if (data) for (size_t row{}; row < numberOfRows; ++row)
        data[row] = static_cast<int*>(std::malloc(numberOfColumns * sizeof(int)));
}

void Array2D::allocaterCalloc() {
    // First get memory to store the row pointer that will later point to the first coulmn of the row
    data = static_cast<int**>(std::calloc(numberOfRows, sizeof(int*)));

    // Now get space for all coulmns in this row
    if (data)for (size_t row{}; row < numberOfRows; ++row)
        data[row] = static_cast<int*>(std::calloc(numberOfColumns, sizeof(int)));
}
void Array2D::allocaterNew() {
    // First get memory to store the row pointer that will later point to the first coulmn of the row
    data = new int* [numberOfRows];

    // Now get space for all coulmns in this row
    if (data) for (size_t row{}; row < numberOfRows; ++row)
        data[row] = new int[numberOfColumns];
}

// --------------------
// And the deallocators
void Array2D::deallocateMallocCalloc() {
    if (data) for (size_t row{}; row < numberOfRows; ++row)
        std::free(data[row]);                   // Free each row with columns
    std::free(data);                            // Free all rows
}
void Array2D::deallocateNew() {
    if (data) for (size_t row{}; row < numberOfRows; ++row)
        delete[] data[row];                     // Free each row with columns
    delete[] data;                              // Free all rows
}
//-------------------------------------------
// Initialize our 2d array with random values
void Array2D::initData() {
    // Seed the random generator
    std::srand(static_cast<unsigned int>(std::time(NULL)));

    // Calculate a random value for all data in our 2d array
    if (data) for (size_t row{}; row < numberOfRows; ++row)                     // For all rows
            if (data[row])  for (size_t col{}; col < numberOfColumns; ++col)    // For all columns
                data[row][col] = LowerBound + (std::rand() % (UpperBound - LowerBound + 1));
}
//--------------------------------------------------------------
// A function which calculates the positive even values of a row
int Array2D::sumOfPositiveEvenValuesIn(size_t row) const {
    int sum{};
    // Iterate over values in a given row
    for (size_t col{}; col < numberOfColumns; ++col)
        // Predicate
        if (data[row] && (data[row][col] > 0) && ((data[row][col] % 2) == 0))
            sum += data[row][col];              // Calculate the sum
    return sum;                                 // Return result
}
//-------------------------------------------------------------------
// Simple output function. Overwrite inserter operator for this class
std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream& os, const Array2D& a2d) {

    // For all rows
    if (a2d.data) for (size_t row{}; row < a2d.numberOfRows; ++row) {

        // For all columns
        if (a2d.data[row]) for (size_t col{}; col < a2d.numberOfColumns; ++col)
            os << a2d.data[row][col] << '\t';                       // Show column values
        os << '\t' << a2d.sumOfPositiveEvenValuesIn(row) << '\n';   // Show conditional sum of columns
    }
    return os << "\n\n";
}
//--------------------------------------
// Bubble sort. Algorithm from Wikipedia
void Array2D::sort() {
    bool swapped{};             // Optimization. If there is now more swap, we can stop
    size_t n{ numberOfRows };   // NUmber of rows in our 2d array
    do {
        swapped = false;        // In the beginning, we did not do any swapping
        for (size_t row{}; row < (n - 1); ++row)

            // We must call the function everytime, because the rows are swapped
            if (sumOfPositiveEvenValuesIn(row) > sumOfPositiveEvenValuesIn(row + 1)) {

                // Swap pointer only. Do not touchg column values at all
                std::swap(data[row], data[row + 1]);
                swapped = true;
            }
        --n;
    } while (swapped);
}

int main() {

    // Define iportant variables
    size_t rowCount{}, columnCount{}, allocaterSelection{};
    Allocater allocater{};
    // Shwo main menu
    std::cout << "\n\nYou need to specify 3 values:\n"
        "1. Enter the allocater method\n"
        "   Enter 1 for malloc      or\n"
        "   Enter 2 for calloc      or\n"
        "   Enter any other number for new\n"
        "2. Then enter the number of rows\n"
        "3. Then enter the number of columns.\n\n";

    // Get user selection and check, if that worked
    if (std::cin >> allocaterSelection >> rowCount >> columnCount) {
        // Depending on user selection for the allocation algorithm
        switch (allocaterSelection) {
        case 1:
            allocater = Allocater::Malloc;
            break;
        case 2:
            allocater = Allocater::Calloc;
            break;
        default: // fallthrough
        case 3:
            allocater = Allocater::New;
            break;
        }

        // Now define our array and initialize all data
        Array2D array2d(rowCount, columnCount, allocater);

        // Show data to user
        std::cout << "\n\n\nData:\n\n" << array2d;

        // Sort
        array2d.sort();

        // Show sorted data to user
        std::cout << "Sorted\n\n" << array2d;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

In case of questions, please ask.